# How do I give permission to a basic user to access read, execute contents of only one partition but not delete or ad files

Tags: permissions

How do I give permission to a basic user to access read, execute contents of only one partition but not delete or ad files ...
I have 3 partitions , and the one I want to give access is dev/sda4 . 
Every time I try to mount disc it requires authentication.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is first, Reading/Writing/Deleting from a filesystem on a partition are managed by a different set of permissions than mounting a filesystem on a partition. So you will need two fixes, at the minimum, to solve your problem.

#### Relevant to Both Fixes

inside of the file `/etc/fstab` there may or may not be a line starting with `/dev/sda4`. Alternatively there may or may not be a line starting with the UUID of that partition. You can find the UUID by running `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid` and looking for the one that points to `/dev/sda4`.

If there isn't a line, then you'll need to make one. Either way, the general form of the line should be:

```
UUID=(hex chars) /mntdir        filesystem    options      0       0
#or
/dev/sda4        /mntdir        filesystem    options      0       0
```

The part of the line you want to focus on is the options section.

#### Fix #1, Relevant if your filesystem is FAT/NTFS

If your filesystem doesn't play nice with linux permissions, then you can use the `umask` option to control the type of access to the files. On NTFS-3G, `umask=0022` sets the user file permissions to `0755` which is `rwxr-xr-x`. `gid` controls what group the default permissions apply to. So for example, you can make a group called `ntfsusers` and add all users to that group and then set `umask=0002` See the Arch Wiki link for more.

```
#Example NTFS line:
/dev/sda4 /mntdir ntfs gid=users,umask=0002,user,rw,auto 0   0
```

#### Fix #2, Mounting the driver as a normal user

The `user` and `nouser` options control who can mount the filesytem.  When `user` is present any user can mount the drive. When `nouser` is present only root can mount the drive. `user` turns on a few other flags by default, see the link at the bottom of this post.

```
#Example NTFS line:
/dev/sda4 /mntdir ext3 defaults,user 0   0
```

Wikipedia on `/etc/fstab`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab
Tuxfiles on `/etc/fstab`: http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html
Arch-Wiki on NTFS-3G options: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTFS-3G#Allowing_Group.2FUser

Comment: You gave a lot of precious information, but in my view you forgot the final part of the answer inside the links. Maybe this is nice to incentive some self-exploration?

Comment: When it comes to permissions, every scenario is unique. In my experience, it is best to indicate the gist of the solution; because the OP may end up rethinking why they need specific permissions before they find the solution. When I first started working with complex permission issues, I ended up changing my mind and redoing it a dozen times or so before I found a good setup.